# Which logs to look when kernel reboots because of panic?

Tags: linux-kernel, reboot, kernel-panic

I wish to set kernel.panic=1 and kernel.panic_on_oops=1.
Is there any log I can check before/after reboot, which will indicate that the reboot was because of a kernel panic?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command ***klogd -f /var/log/kernel.log***.
Haven't used recently but it should work.